# Intel® Xeon® Processor E5-2690 vs Intel® Xeon® Processor E5-2690v2

Tags: vmware-esxi, intel

I have a Fujitsu Primergy RX300 S7 . I've already checked the "official" documents , and called the "official" support to ask if I can install a E5-2690v2 . I was told that Fujitsu only tested their Servers with E5-2690 . So they would not recommend E5-2690v2 .

This is an older server which would become a whole new life with the 10 Core E5-2690v2 .

I already checked the Intel Specifications these two Processors are almost identical, one is Sandy Bridge the other is Ivy Bridge , but from the other technical parameters everything matches .

https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/64596/intel-xeon-processor-e5-2690-20m-cache-2-90-ghz-8-00-gt-s-intel-qpi.html

https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/75279/intel-xeon-processor-e5-2690-v2-25m-cache-3-00-ghz.html

I am really thinking about ordering 2x E5-2690v2 and trying this out on a weekend with the Server . I mean the chances are really high that even though it is not "officially" supported that it will simply just work .

As far as I understand Ivy-Bridge is backwards compatible with Sandy-Bridge.
The Wattage for both CPUs is the same ... so the cooling should be fine.
And the Voltage is also almost the same .

What are you people thinking about this ?

**UPDATE 1 :**
to formulate the Question differently , if I insert the V2 CPU into this Server it might not POST , but it should definitely not damage the motherboard ? And if I have luck and it does POST and VMWARE boots I have luck ?
If these are true , then I will negotiate with our Supplier and ask them if they are willing to give me 2x E5-2690v2 for the Weekend and I will simply try it .

Answer (score 2):

I can only talk about that generational jump on HPE and Cisco servers, both of which required a firmware upgrade be carried out with a v1 CPU in at least one socket before it could then be upgraded to the v2 CPUs. Failure to do so would stop the server even starting its POST.

So I'd be tempted to stick to the supported parts list.

Comment: to formulate the Question differently , if I insert the V2 CPU into this Server it might not POST , but it should definitely not damage the motherboard ? And if I have luck and it does POST and VMWARE boots I have luck ? If these are true , then I will negotiate with our Supplier and ask them if they are willing to give me 2x E5-2690v2 for the Weekend and I will simply try it ... they are pretty cheap nowdays anyway

Comment: You won't know if it'll damage the system until you try it, so I wouldn't do it - serverfault is a site specifically for professional IT staff, we tend to use supported systems and methods.

Comment: I see your point , and I understand it to some degree . But I do like Experimenting . These systems can be bought cheap ... so I'll just buy a used RX300 S7 with 2x E5 2690v2 and test it . For the 2000USD it is worth to test . If this does work I have again a quiet usable VMWARE Host. Thanks

Comment: We like experimenting too - that's important, but more of a superuser.com kind of thing. By the way, if you're looking for something non-production you could build something a lot better just today using something like an AMD Ryzen for a lot less money, wouldn't be production grade however.